# How to open a NSPopover at a distance from the system bar?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nspopover, nsstatusbar

I'm opening a `NSPopover` with the action of an icon in the status bar.

```
myPopover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
```

This works fine with the exception that the distance from the popover and the system bar is zero:

[image]

I'd like to achieve the same result as the Dropbox app which renders the popover at a small distance from the system bar:

[image]

I've tried using `button.bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: 20.0)` which doesn't affect the position of the popover and `button.bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -20.0)` which puts the popover above the system bar:

[image]

So how can I position the `NSPopover` at some distance from the system bar?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried a different coordinate system? Something like `myPopover.show(relativeTo: button.frame.insetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -8.0), of: button.superview, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)`

Comment: Just tried it and it has no effect at all with either positive or negative values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, the reason why `button.bounds.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: -20.0)` didn't work is because those coordinate fell outside the "window" of the status bar item which is the status bar itself. So anything outside of it was cropped.

I solved this problem by collecting information here and there:

1. Create an invisible window.
2. Find the coordinates in the screen of the status bar item and position the invisible window under it.
3. Show the `NSPopover` in relation to the invisible window and not the status bar item.

[image]

The red thing is the invisible window (for demonstration purposes).

## Swift 4 (Xcode 9.2)

```
// Create a window
let invisibleWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 20, 5), styleMask: .borderless, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
invisibleWindow.backgroundColor = .red
invisibleWindow.alphaValue = 0

if let button = statusBarItem.button {
    // find the coordinates of the statusBarItem in screen space
    let buttonRect:NSRect = button.convert(button.bounds, to: nil)
    let screenRect:NSRect = button.window!.convertToScreen(buttonRect)

    // calculate the bottom center position (10 is the half of the window width)
    let posX = screenRect.origin.x + (screenRect.width / 2) - 10
    let posY = screenRect.origin.y

    // position and show the window
    invisibleWindow.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: posX, y: posY))
    invisibleWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)

    // position and show the NSPopover
    mainPopover.show(relativeTo: invisibleWindow.contentView!.frame, of: invisibleWindow.contentView!, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
}
```

I was trying to use `show(relativeTo: invisibleWindow.frame ...)` and the popup wasn't showing up because `NSWindow` is not an `NSView`. For the popup to be displayed a view has to be passed.

Comment: Great solution—however, the NSPopover isn’t focused even when I am using `NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)`. Any clue how to solve this?

Comment: @ixany same problem..did you figure this out?

Comment: @ixany @swiftnoob Try `mainPopover.contentViewController?.view.window?.makeKey()`

Answer (score 2):

you can move the contentView of the popover right after showing it:

```swift
myPopover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)

let popoverWindowX = myPopover.contentViewController?.view.window?.frame.origin.x ?? 0
let popoverWindowY = myPopover.contentViewController?.view.window?.frame.origin.y ?? 0

myPopover.contentViewController?.view.window?.setFrameOrigin(
    NSPoint(x: popoverWindowX, y: popoverWindowY + 20)
)

myPopover.contentViewController?.view.window?.makeKey()
```

in terms of UI you will get a slight slide of the arrow but in your case, with the very small padding, it'll be most imperceptible.

i'm using something similar to make sure my popover doesn't go offscreen. you can see the slight slide.

[image: popover sliding]